# In R, how to create contour plot where lines indicate elevation and color indicate magnitude of a separate value?

Tags: r, data-visualization

My specific example: I have a dataframe, say 'df', containing columns of x coordinates, y coordinates, elevation, and I have a vector of precipitation values associated with the x/y coordinates (say the variable name is 'prec').

I can create a 3d representation with:

```
myColorRamp <- function(colors, values) {
v <- (values - min(values))/diff(range(values))
x <- colorRamp(colors)(v)
rgb(x[,1], x[,2], x[,3], maxColorValue = 255)
}
library(rgl)
cols <- myColorRamp(c("red", "white", "blue"), prec)
plot3d(df$xcoord, df$ycoord, df$Elev, type="p", size=3, xlab='x', ylab='y', zlab='elevation', col = cols)
```

I'm looking to basically have a 2d representation of the same picture, where instead of a 3d plot, the 3rd dimension of elevation is represented using contour lines.

ie: I want a contour plot like so:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/ContourPlot_1000.gif
but instead of the colors indicating magnitude of the elevation, I want it to indicate the levels of precipitation.

I've looked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31726/scatterplot-with-contour-heat-overlay and [R: Scatterplot with too many points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714677/r-scatterplot-with-too-many-points) but they don't seem to apply to this particular problem and I'm struggling with the example given in http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/filled.contour.html because my z value is a vector, not a matrix.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Posting df or a sample of df here e.g. using command head(df) or head(df, 10) and also 'prec' will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: What does `my z value is a vector, not a matrix` mean? Can you not create a matrix? That's a very standard way to store 3d data

Comment: possible duplicate of [spatial data xyz to matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208750/spatial-data-xyz-to-matrix)

Comment: possible duplicate of [R: Plotting a 3D surface from x, y, z](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979240/r-plotting-a-3d-surface-from-x-y-z)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert first your `df$xcoord`,`df$ycoord`,`df$Elev` vectors to a `matrix`.

Basically create a grid and fill it with the points that you have in your vectors. Some points of the grid will remain NA, but that should work.

See also [this existing stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208750/spatial-data-xyz-to-matrix)
EDIT: all the information is also available [in this existing stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979240/r-plotting-a-3d-surface-from-x-y-z)